# swift 3, JSON, invalid top-level type when writing

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have two exactly json objects, one is created from a function, the other is hard-coded, the hardcoded one works, the other doesn't (it always complains about the error `invalid top-level type` , which is weird. Any tip? Tks

```
let myData = self.dailyMileage?.toDictionary()

let directData = ["orgId" : self.orgId, "driverId" : self.driverId, "date" : Utils.getTodaysDate() ] as [String : Any]

//this won't work unless I substitute myData with directData                        
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myData, options: .prettyPrinted)

//this is the function that produces myData, and nothing is nil
 public func toDictionary() -> [String : Any] {
    let dict = [ "orgId" : orgId , "driverId": driverId, "date" : date] as [String : Any]
    return dict
}
```

Comment: Is the problem because `myData` is optional?

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint the jsonData line to inspect the myData instance and make sure it is actually correct?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup yes, I did, that's why I said they're exactly the same

Comment: is your `myData` object optional? It looks like it is. The reason may be because of that. Please check my answer and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

`JSONSerialization` as given in the documentation:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
>
> All dictionary keys are instances of NSString. Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling isValidJSONObject(_:) or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be converted to JSON data.

1. I think the one that's coming from the function might have an NSDate object instead of an NSString object.
2. The other reason is because your `myData` object is optional. `JSONSerialization` may give an error like that is the object is optional.

Please check if it is due to one of those two reasons. Feel free to suggest edits to make it better.